# Attribute error while creating list from string values

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have imported excel file with some data and removed missing values.

`df = pd.read_excel (r'file.xlsx', na_values = missing_values)`

Im trying to split string values to make them into list for later actions.

`df['GENRE'] = df['GENRE'].map(lambda x: x.split(','))
 df['ACTORS'] = df['ACTORS'].map(lambda x: x.split(',')[:3])
 df['DIRECTOR'] = df['DIRECTOR'].map(lambda x: x.split(','))`

But it gives me following error - `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`
I've done the same with csv and it worked.. could it be because its excel?
Im sure it's simple but i can't get my head around it.[example of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyU8q.png)

Comment: please show a sample of the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Try using `str.split`, the Pandas way:

```
df['GENRE'] = df['GENRE'].str.split(',')
df['ACTORS'] = df['ACTORS'].str.split(',').str[:3]
df['DIRECTOR'] = df['DIRECTOR'].str.split(',')
```